# passing data from byte array(with zeros) to istringstream(stringstream)

Tags: c++, stringstream, istringstream

why this code

```
char magicData [] = { 0x00i8, 0xfdi8, 0xffi8, 0xfci8, 0x00i8,
                      0xf3i8, 0xf4i8, 0xf5i8, 0x00i8};
std::string s;
std::istringstream ss(magicData, sizeof(magicData));
while(std::getline(ss, s))
{
std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

don't produce any output? (using stringstream instead of istringstream doesn't help).
As result i expect 2 line of string (without 0x00 at end). 
How to solve it?

Comment: I think, you should check description of `std::istringstream` constructors to start with...

Comment: What is `magic`? Don't you mean `magicData`?

Comment: oh sorry, magicData of course

Answer (score 1):

`std::istringstream` doesn't have a constructor that takes an array. You're actually calling the constructor that takes a C-style string and an `openmode`. All you need for this to work is:

```
std::istringstream ss(std::string(magic, magic + sizeof(magic)));
```

Comment: magicData does not include '\0'. Your answer and OP example will produce UB.

Comment: but... `char magicData[] = "line1\n line 2\n";` works => istringstream  have this such of constructor